# Creating Custom Magento Module. Not detecting template

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am creating a custom module with a new URL. As of right now. If I put a echo into my Indexcontroller class and goto mydomain.com/index.php/advancedcatalog, It detects the echo But it does not detect my view. Here is my structure

/Advancedcatalog/Block/Advancedcatalog.php

### Advancedcatalog.php

```
<?php
class Webwow_Advancedcatalog_Block_Advancedcatalog extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getHelloworld()
    {
        return 'Hello world';
    }
}
```

/Advancedcatalog/controllers/IndexController.php

### IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Webwow_Advancedcatalog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

/Advancedcatalog/Model/Advancedcatalog.php

### Advancedcatalog.php

```
<?php 
class Webwow_Advancedcatalog_Model_Advancedcatalog extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('advancedcatalog/advancedcatalog');
    }
}
```

/Advancedcatalog/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Webwow_Advancedcatalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Webwow_Advancedcatalog>
    </modules>
     <frontend>
        <routers>
            <advancedcatalog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Webwow_Advancedcatalog</module>
                    <frontName>advancedcatalog</frontName>
                </args>
            </advancedcatalog>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <advancedcatalog>
                    <file>advancedcatalog.xml</file>
                </advancedcatalog>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <advancedcatalog>
                <class>Webwow_Advancedcatalog_Block</class>
            </advancedcatalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my layout

### /layout/advancedcatalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <advancedcatalog_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="advancedcatalog/advancedcatalog" name="advancedcatalog"
            template="advancedcatalog/helloworld.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </advancedcatalog_index_index>
</layout>
```

### /templates/advancedcatalog/helloworld.phtml

```
<h2><?php echo $this->getHelloworld(); ?></h2>
TESTING
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue. I accidently had the layout file in the wrong themes

Comment: Could you possibly take a look at my question and share your gained knowledge?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280147/load-magento-module-template

Any help appreciated