# Load Magento module template

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

For a Magento module I need to load template file and let it replace the complete page. It is a XML file (but could also be any content whatsoever).
Generally speaking when

`MYNS_MYMODULE_controllernameController` is triggered and calls `fooAction()` I need to be able to display a clean site with the content from my template file.

Please let me know where to place the template file and how to tell Magento to load this file as a root template without anything else around.

Edit, to clarify it more:

For http://domain.tld/**modulename**/**controller**/**action**/

Where do I have to place template files and how should I reference them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
  $this->loadLayout()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
  $this->renderLayout();
```

or to set a custom response

```
 //$file = myfile or html

 $this->getResponse()->setBody($file);
 $this->renderLayout();
```

Ideally your template should sit in /app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/mytemplate.phtml

Comment: Thanks, will test this ASAP. Do you know if it is legit to store the file in /code/community/MyNS/MyModule/Template/... as well? Does it make a difference for packaging of the final extension?

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Magento doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html) and [Alan Storm Blog](http://alanstorm.com/). Alan also wrote a book about Magento Layout: *No Frills Magento Layout*.

Your url: `http://domain.tld/modulename/controller/action/`

The `modulename_controller_action` Handle is created by combining *the route name* (`modulename`), *Action Controller name* (`controller`), and *Action Controller Action Method* (`action`) into a single string. This means each possible method on an Action Controller has a Handle associated with it.
In your layout xml handles this request:

```
<modulename_controller_action>
     ......
</modulename_controller_action>
```

Hope my suggestion is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, your input is appreciated.